# Is there an up to date list of malicious IPs so that I can block them?

Tags: security, ip, malicious

I'm looking for a comprehensive and up to date list of malicious IPs from all around the world so that I can block them in the servers I manage.
I searched the net alot for it but I couldn't find anything that matched my criteria.
it would be very great if someone could provide such a list.

Comment: Yeah, 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255.  Every single one of them.

Comment: Hamed - don't EVER mod-alert us again for what is a great comment to a stupid question or we'll destroy your account.

Comment: If you want Spamhaus's opinion of Melicious IPs, they have a [DROP Project](http://www.spamhaus.org/drop/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be no such list, for two reasons.

1. "Malicious" is relative. A file-sharing site may want to block **AA addresses, whereas most people won't care about them.
2. Malicious is relative. Botnets expand and shift, which means that a previously-safe address is now a problem.

Comment: But I have seen such lists in the net. by malicious IPs I mean the ones that have been frequently reported as threatening by multiple servers around the globe, or some port scanner robots and something like these.